How to find an SQL error in Crystal Reports?
My code is returning an error :
Error Screenshot
Here is my code :
SELECT
"OINV"."DocNum" [Transaction Number],
"OINV"."DocDate",
"OINV"."CardName",
"INV1"."Dscription",
"OINV"."CardCode",
"OINV"."BPLName",
"INV1"."LineTotal",
"INV1"."GTotal",
"OACT"."AcctCode",
"OACT"."AcctName",
"OINV"."LicTradNum",
"OINV"."Pindicator",
"INV1"."Itemcode"
FROM   ("Database"."dbo"."OACT" "OACT" INNER JOIN "Database"."dbo"."INV1" "INV1" ON "OACT"."AcctCode"="INV1"."AcctCode") INNER JOIN "Database"."dbo"."OINV" "OINV" ON "INV1"."DocEntry"="OINV"."DocEntry"
UNION
SELECT
"OCSI"."DocNum"[Transaction Number],
"OCSI"."DocDate",
"OCSI"."CardName",
"CSI1"."Dscription",
"OCSI"."CardCode",
"OCSI"."BPLName",
"CSI1"."LineTotal",
"CSI1"."GTotal",
"OACT"."AcctCode",
"OACT"."AcctName",
"OCSI"."LicTradNum",
"OCSI"."Pindicator",
"CSI1"."Itemcode"
FROM   ("Database"."dbo"."OCSI" "OCSI" INNER JOIN "Database"."dbo"."CSI1" "CSI1" ON "OCSI"."DocEntry"="CSI1"."DocEntry") INNER JOIN "Database"."dbo"."OACT" "OACT" ON "CSI1"."AcctCode"="OACT"."AcctCode"
UNION
SELECT
"ORIN"."DocNum"[Transaction Number],
"ORIN"."DocDate",
"ORIN"."CardName",
"RIN1"."Dscription",
"ORIN"."CardCode",
"ORIN"."BPLName",
"RIN1"."LineTotal"*-1,
"RIN1"."GTotal",
"OACT"."AcctCode",
"OACT"."AcctName",
"ORIN"."LicTradNum",
"ORIN"."Pindicator",
"RIN1"."Itemcode"
FROM   ("Database"."dbo"."ORIN" "ORIN" INNER JOIN "Database"."dbo"."RIN1" "RIN1" ON "ORIN"."DocEntry"="RIN1"."DocEntry") INNER JOIN "Database"."dbo"."OACT" "OACT" ON "RIN1"."AcctCode"="OACT"."AcctCode"
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."LineId",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_CardCode",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_Comments",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_ItemCode",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M01Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M02Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M03Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M04Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M05Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M06Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M07Amnt ",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M08Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M09Amnt"
FROM   "Database"."dbo"."@PM_BGT_CNT" "_PM_BGT_CNT" INNER JOIN "Database"."dbo"."OACT" "OACT" ON "_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_SalesAcc"="OACT"."AcctCode"
My question is how to find were in my code the error is. There no line number or anything to tell me were the error is coming from.
Please help it's driving me mad!
Kind wishes,
Simon.
As can been seen there are four nests of tables, then union joined to each other.
The first three nests work well together but it's only when I bring in the fourth nest that this error occurs. The fourth nest work fine by itself but something goes wrong when it linked to the others.

UNION statements require that columns -- by their positions -- across all statements agree in terms of data type. Locate which column N in statement 4 has a different data type from column N in the previous statements.
Also, keep in mind that UNION removes duplicates (which is a slow process) while UNION ALL is much faster because it doesn't remove duplicates. If you don't need to remove duplicates, use UNION ALL.

That took all day to fix and it worked thank you very much. However the fourth nest of tables doesn't appear in the field explorer - Database Fields - Command Field List.

Any ideas why? - probably something stupid on my part. Can you help?

Sorry, your new question seems difficult to understand. Please close this thread and start a new question with more detail.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1734722/milletsoftware Thanks for your help, I learned a few new things, thanks to you and its much appreciated.
